# How to register app to share all types of files?

Tags: android, intentfilter

I am trying to use intent filters to do this. I tried this [Intent filter for files only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247957/intent-filter-for-files-only) but it didn't work. I want to make my app appear in the share menu for all types of files.

Here my intent filter

```
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="content" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
                <data android:host="*" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Try this
<data android:scheme="content" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
                <data android:host="*" />

Comment: @AnkitaShah I tried this `<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="content" />
                <data android:mimeType="/" />
                <data android:host="*" />
            </intent-filter>` but it complained malformed manifest code

Comment: Now try `<data android:scheme="content" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
                <data android:host="*" />`

Comment: Ya I think you should go with @AnkitaShah solution.

Comment: @AnkitaShah unfortunately didn't work :/ I tried this `<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="content" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
                <data android:host="*" />
            </intent-filter>` and then tried to share a pdf file. The app didn't show up in the menu.

Comment: Any error are you getting? @Saumya

Comment: @PratikDasa Nope, no errors. If it helps I am posting all the intent filters used by my activity.

Comment: check @AnkitaShah answer below, its working in my project as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It's working in my project

```
      <intent-filter>
            <!---->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks !! I have been trying this for days :D